# Need to count rows until a certain condition is given

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with ID and a flag

| ID | flag | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | YES | 2022-10-01 |
| user_1 | YES | 2022-09-01 |
| user_1 | NO | 2022-07-01 |
| user_1 | YES | 2022-06-01 |
| user_1 | YES | 2022-05-01 |
| user_1 | YES | 2022-04-01 |
| user_2 | YES | 2022-10-01 |
| user_2 | YES | 2022-09-01 |
| user_2 | YES | 2022-08-01 |
| user_2 | NO | 2022-06-01 |
| user_2 | YES | 2022-05-01 |
| user_2 | YES | 2022-04-01 |

I want to count al the "YES" values, but only until the first "NO" is found
In this case i want to get something like:

| ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2 |
| user_2 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, count(*) `count` from (
  select * from your_table
  qualify countif(flag='NO') over(partition by id order by month desc) = 0
)
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem and some problems with the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can seqarch first for the last Date when then No occurs and then filter all Dates that are greater than the date for the No

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT `ID`, MAX( `month`) max_date FROM Table1 WHERE `flag` = 'NO' GROUP BY `ID`)
SELECT t1.`ID`, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN CTE c ON t1.`ID` = c.`ID`AND t1.`month` > c.max_date
GROUP BY t1.`ID`
```

| ID | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2 |
| user_2 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks! but with this method it "deleted" the cases where i did not have a  "NO"

Comment: then change the inner join with LEFT to get all cases